# Merge two queries with DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have my main entity `poi` that has two `OneToOne` relation with my two other entities `people` and `places`.

**App/Entity/People.php**

```
class People
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Poi", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $poi;
```

**App/Entity/Places.php**

```
class Places
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Poi", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $poi;
```

Now I need to get the `people`and `places` in the same array or something. I got that by merging two queries :

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery('select p from App:People p'); //same for places then merge in array...
```

Q : Is there a way to get the same result with one DQL query? (especially if the entities don't have the same columns).

Answer (score 0):

To simply get all `People` and `Places` in one array you can go with:

```php
$query = $entityManager->createQuery('select people, places from App:People people, App:Places places');
```

I guess you will want to fetch them for a given `Poi`, in that case if you only have the poi id you can try this:

```php
$query = $entityManager
    ->createQuery('select people, places from App:People people, App:Places places where people.poi = :poi and places.poi = :poi')
    ->setParameter('poi', $poiId)
;
```

Naturally, if you have a `Poi` entity object at your disposal, you can simply do

```php
$peopleAndPlaces = [$poi->getPeople(), $poi->getPlaces()]
```

Note that in order for above code to work you have to add those methods to respective entity classes and make sure the relations with `Poi` are [bidirectional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional)

If you for whatever reason often need to get that array and you have a `Poi` entity object, it might be a good idea to add a method to the `Poi` class

```php
class Poi
{
    ...

    public function getPeopleAndPlaces()
    {
        return [$this->getPeople(), $this->getPlaces()];
    }
```

and then call `$poi->getPeopleAndPlaces()` when needed.